# Prometheus: How to get SUM of all unique records for a time period? Not a SUM of VALUES

Tags: prometheus

Is it possible to get SUM of all unique records for a time period? Not the SUM of values.

For example, I have these records for a few days

```
awsec2_api{alias="awsec2metrics", instance_id="i-05a7d9e565ac8b7" reachability="initializing", state="running", systemstatus="initializing", zone="us-east-1c"}16
```

One instance can have different statuses for 24 hours.

I would like to get SUM of instances for 24 hours like this:

```
Total istances = 17
Initializing instances = 12
Running = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified metric output and separate into three metrics: instancestate, instancestatus, systemstatus.

For example Instance State:

```
ec2_inststate{alias="awsec2metrics", application="name", aws_autoscaling_groupName="name", exported_job="monitoring", instance="localhost:9091", instance_id="ide8", instancestate="16", job="pushgateway", role="name" zone="us-east-1"}16
```

Responce codes

- 0 : pending
- 16 : running
- 32 : shutting-down
- 48 : terminated
- 64 : stopping
- 80 : stopped

This request calculate SUM of instances with code 16 for 1 hour.

```
(sum by (value) (sum_over_time(ec2_inststate{alias="awsec2metrics",instancestate="16"}[1h])))/16
```